# yum install obsolete openoffice instead of libreoffice

Tags: yum, openoffice

Unfortunately the software that I'm using (Alfresco) requires the installation of openoffice, and not libreoffice.  If I try and configure it to use libreoffice I receive errors during startup.  If I try to install any of the openoffice packages:

```
yum install openoffice*
```

I receive errors for all packages similar to:

```
Package openoffice.org-langpack-bg_BG is obsoleted by libreoffice-langpack-bg, trying to install 1:libreoffice-langpack-bg-3.4.5.2-16.el6.x86_64 instead
```

Then it proceeds to try and download libreoffice.  I don't see anything in `man yum` with regards to installing obsolete packages.  Is there any way to install obsolete packages via yum and not their newer counterparts?

Comment: same problem installing languageweaver.  @BengiWiebe below solved my problem perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you prefer, you can download the proper package (deb, rpm..) from the official website: 
http://www.openoffice.org/download/other.html

After you can install with rpm or with yum.

Answer (score 12):

I found that, when installing `openoffice`, adding `exclude=libreoffice*` to your `/etc/yum.conf` helped with `sudo yum update`, and I am sure that it would help with your problem too. It tells `yum` to ignore `libreoffice*` packages, therefore `yum` does not even know that there is a package that obsoletes `openoffice`.

Comment: Best solution because you don't have to download anything manually.  Also you don't have to `yum clean all` and rebuild the cache in case you were wondering.

Comment: Important to note that if it's a single command you are running (e.g. in a script), you don't need to mess around with `yum.conf`—you can just use `--exclude=libreoffice\*` as a flag to `yum` directly on the command line.

Answer (score 8):

```
sudo yum --setopt=obsoletes=0 install openoffice*
```

Or you can put `obsoletes=0` to `/etc/yum.conf`

Both ways worked for me on `Oracle Linux 6.7`.